# How to print all codes in a solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a tool in VS2019 by which we can export all codes in a solution to PDF or another format?

Comment: what kind of codes are you after? You mean to print the entire source-code to PDF?

Comment: but..... _why_?

Answer (score 1):

You can print from Visual Studio 2019, so install a PDF printer (it may already exist as Microsoft Print to PDF), and then simply print, and it will create a PDF of your source code.

You will have to do this for each file individually, however.

Otherwise simply create your own program to scan for .cs files and print them to PDF.